# mounting directories using docker operator on airflow is not working

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm trying to use the docker operator to automate the execution of some scripts using airflow.

Airflow version: `apache-airflow==1.10.12`

What I want to do is to "copy" all my project's files (with folders and files) to the container using this code.

The following file `ml-intermediate.py` is in this directory `~/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate.py`:

```
"""
Template to convert a Ploomber DAG to Airflow
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

from ploomber.spec import DAGSpec
from soopervisor.script.ScriptConfig import ScriptConfig

script_cfg = ScriptConfig.from_path('/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate')
# Replace the project root to reflect the new location - or maybe just
# write a soopervisor.yaml, then we can we rid of this line
script_cfg.paths.project = '/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate'

# TODO: use lazy_import from script_cfg
dag_ploomber = DAGSpec('/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate/pipeline.yaml',
                       lazy_import=True).to_dag()
dag_ploomber.name = "ML Intermediate"

default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
}

dag_airflow = DAG(
    dag_ploomber.name.replace(' ', '-'),
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Ploomber dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
)

script_cfg.save_script()

from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
for task_name in dag_ploomber:
    DockerOperator(task_id=task_name,
        image="continuumio/miniconda3",
        api_version="auto",
        auto_remove=True,
        # command="sh /home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate/script.sh",
        command="sleep 600",
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        volumes=[
            "/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate:/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate:rw",
            "/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate:/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate:rw"
        ],
        working_dir=script_cfg.paths.project,
        dag=dag_airflow,
        container_name=task_name,
    )



for task_name in dag_ploomber:
    task_ploomber = dag_ploomber[task_name]
    task_airflow = dag_airflow.get_task(task_name)

    for upstream in task_ploomber.upstream:
        task_airflow.set_upstream(dag_airflow.get_task(upstream))

dag = dag_airflow
```

When I execute this DAG using Airflow, I get the error that the docker does not find the `/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate/script.sh` script. I changed the execution command of the docker operator `sleep 600` to enter to the container and check the files in the container with the corrects paths.

When I'm in the container I can go to this path `/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate/` for example, but I don't see the files that are supposed to be there.

I tried to replicate how Airflow implements [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) checking this part of the package [docker operator Airflow](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py), specifically, this one where it creates the docker container: [docker container creation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py#L231)

This is my one replication of the docker implementation:

```
import docker

client = docker.APIClient()

# binds = {
#         "/home/letyndr/airflow/dags": {
#             "bind": "/home/letyndr/airflow/dags",
#             "mode": "rw"
#         },
#         "/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate": {
#             "bind": "/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate",
#             "mode": "rw"
#         }
#     }

binds = ["/home/letyndr/airflow/dags:/home/letyndr/airflow/dags:rw",
"/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate:/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate:rw"]

container = client.create_container(
    image="continuumio/miniconda3",
    command="sleep 600",
    volumes=["/home/letyndr/airflow/dags", "/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate"],
    host_config=client.create_host_config(binds=binds),
    working_dir="/home/letyndr/airflow/dags",
    name="simple_example",
)

client.start(container=container.get("Id"))
```

What I found was that mounting volumes only works if it's set `host_config` and `volumes`, the problem is that the implementation on Airflow just set `host_config` but not `volumes`. I added the parameter on the method `create_container`, it worked.

Do you know if I'm using docker operator correctly or is this an issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `mounts` argument instead of `volumes`. That's how volumes are defined in the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html) / [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-1-stable/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py#L98).

So it should look something like this:

```
DockerOperator(task_id=task_name,
        image="continuumio/miniconda3",
        api_version="auto",
        auto_remove=True,
        # command="sh /home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate/script.sh",
        command="sleep 600",
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        mounts=[
            "/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate:/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate:rw",
            "/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate:/home/letyndr/airflow-data/ml-intermediate:rw"
        ],
        working_dir=script_cfg.paths.project,
        dag=dag_airflow,
        container_name=task_name,
    )
```

These are a some other optional arguments that might be helpful:

1. *host_tmp_dir:* Specify the location of the temporary directory on the host which will be mapped to `tmp_dir`. If not provided defaults to using the standard system temp directory.
2. *tmp_dir:* Mount point inside the container to a temporary directory created on the host by the operator
   *tmp_dir:*

**EDIT:** After additional review I see that each `mount` item must be of type `Mount` from `docker.types`. The argument `volumes` was also renamed to `mount` as part of the Changelog for Airflow 2.1. Here is an example from the [Airflow source code](https://github.com/TimJLS/airflow/blob/7a34cc5e0daac1924e3c10e4aba82add7e8aaf10/tests/providers/docker/operators/test_docker.py).

Revised, the code should look something akin to

```
from docker.types import Mount 

...
...

DockerOperator(task_id=task_name,
    image="continuumio/miniconda3",
    api_version="auto",
    auto_remove=True,
    # command="sh /home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate/script.sh",
    command="sleep 600",
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    mounts=[
        Mount(
            source='/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate', 
            target='/home/letyndr/airflow/dags/ml-intermediate:rw', 
            type='bind'
        )
    ],
    working_dir=script_cfg.paths.project,
    dag=dag_airflow,
    container_name=task_name,
)
```